# drupal 7 create an alias view alias with arguments

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-path-aliases

I have an url  like this:
http://www.mysite.com/myview?arg1=3&arg2=4.

It points to a view.

I would like ,  for a specific compination of arguments,   a shorter url alias

something like http://www.mysite.com/myalias that point to the same page.

I did try to add an url alias on drupal cms by here  admin/config/search/path/add or by htaccess, 
but I think I think  to do that I need the "real" url of the view (the one that doesn't use Path auto, I guess)

Does someone know how to retrieve it?
or anyway  does anyone know how to solve this issue?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this module helps you: https://drupal.org/project/views_url_path_arguments

It has not a final version, but I think you might find it useful.

Regards.

Comment: hi I am not sure it is useful,  it seems it is for creating url without arguments,  but I don't think  i can create short url.  Am I right?